# List of filename in each subdirectory using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

I have many subdirectory ie sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4 and so on.

I want to save only filename in each subdirectory but by using batch file which is at Main directory ie DIR1.

I know this code: `DIR /B /ON *.txt > filelist.txt`.

But this code save filename in same folder  ie sub1 and i wanted DIR1 folder batch file to execute program that can save only filename in each subdirectories.

For Example:

```
+Main Directory(DIR1 folder)

execute.bat

++Sub1 folder:

mu1111.txt 

++sub2 folder:

mu2222.txt

++sub3 folder:

mu3333.txt
```

When i run execute.bat the output will be shown like this:

```
+Main Directory(DIR1 folder)

execute.bat

++Sub1 folder:

mu1111.txt 

filelist.txt

++sub2 folder:

mu2222.txt

filelist.txt

++sub3 folder:

mu3333.txt

filelist.txt
```

Plus I want that this code does not get executed in folders  of subdirectories.

Comment: Prefix mu from each filename is deleted in filelist.txt after its generation.Example; When filelist.txt is open then it should be like this:1111.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is designed to create `filelist.txt` in each subdirectory

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\Main Directory\DIR1"
   for /d %%a in (*) do (
       DIR /B /ON /A-D "%%a\*.txt" > filelist.txt.
       move filelist.txt "%%a" >nul
   )
```

Comment: Prefix mu from each filename is deleted in filelist.txt after its generation.Example; When filelist.txt is open then it should be like this:1111.txt and not mu1111.txt

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `tree` command with the `/f` switch so that filenames are listed too:

```
tree /f
```

Output looks like this:

[image: Output looks like this]

Answer (score 1):

```
for /d /r "c:\Main Directory\DIR1" %%a in (*) do (
    >"%%~fa\filelist.txt" dir /on /b /a-d "%%~fa\*"
)
```

For each folder (`/d`), recursively under the indicated root (`/r`) , execute a dir command of the folder contents to the filelist.txt file inside the corresponding folder.